# Python Type Error: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a problem with the error 'module' object is not callable.
I'm using this pyAesCrypt library to encrypt/decrypt a password.

Here I define a class User to store the password encrypted in the db, running the application.
Then I need to query the encrypted password from the db and decrypt it, passing it into a variable.
So here's the class I defined:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
#from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
import pyAesCrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///data-users2.sqlite"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    pwd = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, id, username, pwd):
        p = pyAesCrypt(encoding=False)
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.pwd = p.encrypt("password",pwd)
```

Here I query the password from db and decrypt it, but it seems that there is something wrong where I call the module pyAesCrypt, the error is below. Anyone can see any anomaly? If yes could you please edit my code in the correct way? thanks.

```
import pyAesCrypt
        
#get FTP pwd
user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(username="ita_itf").first()
p_decrypt = pyAesCrypt(encoding=False)
DICP_FTP_DESTINATION_PSW = p_decrypt.decrypt("password",user.pwd)
```

ERROR:

```
p_decrypt = pyAesCrypt(encoding=False)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Maybe `pyAesCrypt` has a function of the same name within the module, a bit like `datetime.datetime()`. So it might be a bit like this: `from pyAesCrypt import pyAesCrypt`

Answer (score 1):

What you did is `p_decrypt = pyAesCrypt(encoding=False)`

**pyAescrypt** is module name, you still need to tell the module what you want it to do, like **encrypt** or **decrypt**

What you should do is smthg like

```
p_decrypt = pyAesCrypt.decryptStream("password",user.pwd)
```

Else, full [AesCrypt Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyAesCrypt/)

Comment: ok Thanks, this examples works only for files though, I need to decrypt a password

Comment: I have found this documentation which seems to be the correct one to decrypt a password https://github.com/ninjatrench/PyAESCrypt

Comment: also in the function decryptStream() you need to pass 4 arguments : fIn, fOut, password, bufferSize, not sure what fln,fOut is , I think this is for files encryption, not for password strings

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the docs it looks like you are missing a call to the necessary function. In this case I think what you want is the `pyAesCrypt.decryptStream()` method. Take a look at the docs [here (under the binary stream section)](https://github.com/marcobellaccini/pyAesCrypt#module-usage-example) for details.

Comment: Great thanks! Is not very clear to me what should I pass in   fIn, fOut, what is that? I only have to pass a password, > pyAesCrypt.encryptStream(fIn, fOut, password, bufferSize)

Comment: pyAesCrypt.decryptStream() , you need to pass 4 arguments, I have no idea what are the other arguments I should pass, I just have a password to decrypt

Comment: This seems to be the correct way https://github.com/ninjatrench/PyAESCrypt

Comment: but returns that error

Comment: @MarcelloLigi that package you mentioned is completely different than the PyPi one. So if you did ```pip install pyAesCrypt``` that method wont work. For that version you need to use ```from PyAesCrypt import PyAesCrypt``` for it to work.

Comment: i suggest to modify your script based on pyAesCrypt official documentation or to rewrite it using cryptography module.

Comment: @Kieran Wood not true, if you do that it says theres no module named PyAesCrypt, but is pyAesCrypt, and anyway I used the same code to encrypt the password and it works, it doesn't work when trying to decrypt it. the difference is that I encrypt it in the class and I'm trying to decrypt it in the form, when importing the class User

Comment: @CYREX  in the documentation is not very clear how to decrypt a password string, there are only a few explainations in the official documentation, mostly on how to decrypt files not password strings. Not very clear to me what are the arguments that I should pass to pyAesCrypt.decryptStream(), it seems there are 4 arguments to pass but not explained what they are.

Comment: For instance fIn fOut , what are they? Is not explained in the docs! They just give for granted you already know what that is.

Comment: I believe that the following code should be the correct way, as it worked for me when I encrypt the pwd in the class User:

Comment: a = PyAesCrypt()   //////////
  d = a.decrypt("password",b'2B22cS3UC5s35WBihLBo8w==')